# Unable to Create Payment for order using Rest API

Tags: acumatica

While trying to Create the Payment at Payments and application screen,facing the below issue

> "exceptionMessage": "PX.Data.PXRowPersistingException: Error: 'OrigDocAmt' cannot be empty.\r\n   at PX.Data.PXDefaultAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row, Boolean bypassInterceptor)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()\r\n   at PX.Objects.AR.ARPaymentEntry.Persist() in C:\Bld\AC-FULL2018R24-JOB1\sources\WebSites\Pure\PX.Objects\AR\ARPaymentEntry.cs:line 2458\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.<Handler>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__32.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__32.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1, PXFilterRow[] A_2)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()\nPayment.CashAccount: 'Cash Account' cannot be empty.\nPayment.CustomerID: Error: 'Customer' cannot be empty.\nPayment.PaymentMethod: 'Payment Method' cannot be empty.",

```
{
"Type" : { "Value":"Payment" },
"CustomerID" : { "Value":"10101010"},
"PaymentMethod" : { "Value":"CHECK"},
"PaymentRef" : { "Value": "123456789" },
"PaymentAmount" : { "Value": "250" },
"Branch" : {"Value":"PRODWHOLE"} --->Financial  setting tab
```

}

Comment: I Have tried with Contract based api through dotnet code it is working fine.When trying with the rest API in Postman facing the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

the thing is REST API is case sensitive, so you need to use lowercase "value" keyword:

```
{
"Type" : { "value":"Payment" },
"CustomerID" : { "value":"ABARTENDE"},
"PaymentMethod" : { "value":"CHECK"},
"PaymentRef" : { "value": "123456789" },
"PaymentAmount" : { "value": "250" },
"Branch" : {"value":"PRODWHOLE"} 
}
```

By the way, please note that starting from 2019r1 version of Acumatica ERP, you can send Sales Order with Payments in a single call:

```
Put: {{sitename}}/entity/Default/18.200.001/SalesOrder?$select=OrderNbr,CashAccount
{
"CashAccount": {
    "value": "10200"
},
"CustomerID": {
    "value": "ABARTENDE"
},
"Details": [
    {
        "BranchID": {
            "value": "HQ"
        },"InventoryID": {
            "value": "AAMACHINE"
        },
        "OrderQty": {
            "value": 1
        },
    "UnitPrice": {
            "value": 269.85
        },
    "WharehouseID": {
            "value": "WHOLESALE"
        },
    "ManualPrice": {
            "value": true
            }
    }
],
"OrderType": {
    "value": "SO"
},
"PaymentMethod": {
    "value": "CHECK"
},
  "ExternalRef": {
    "value": "9593"
},
"Payments": [
    {
        "PaymentRef": {
            "value": "SOpay123"
        },
        "AppliedToOrder": {
            "value": 269.85
        },
        "CashAccount": {
            "value": "10300"
        },
        "PaymentMethod": {
            "value": "CHECK"
        }
    }
]
}
```